# Spring cloud pass arguments

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, spring-cloud-config

I have application already configured with spring cloud config , I want to pass jvm agrument to run this application :

bootsrap.yml config

```
  spring.application.name: app
spring.cloud.config:
  enabled: ${SPRING_CONFIG_ENABLED:false}
  uri: ${SPRING_CONFIG_URI:http://ip:9097/}
```

I want to pass argument like this but not work :

```
gradle bootRunLocal -DSPRING_CONFIG_ENABLED=true     -DSPRING_CONFIG_URI=http://localhost:9097/
```

Comment: Is your file really called `bootsrap.yml` (instead of `bootstrap.yml`)? Does that first line really have those two spaces?

Comment: the name of file is bootstrap.yml , the problem is fixed thanks ;

Answer (score 0):

Try to configure bootrun task in build.gradle file as bellow:

```
bootRun {
    systemProperties System.properties
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix problem by adding this code in  bootRun:

```
   bootRun {
        if (project.hasProperty('args')) {
            args project.args.split(',')
        }
    }
```

to run task :

```
gradle bootRun -Pargs=--spring.profiles.active=local,--SPRING_CONFIG_ENABLED=true,--SPRING_CONFIG_URI=http://localhost:9097/
```